# Get input text from corresponding radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two radio buttons with an input text for each radio button, where a person selects a radio button and enters text.

The question is: How do I get the typed text for the selected radio button?

Comment: In English please

Comment: Can you please provide a "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example"? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="textNome" class="control-label">Type text</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="one" checked /> Selection 
1</label>
<input id="end" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
<div class="radio">
<label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="two"checked /> Selection 
2</label>
<input id="end" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using jQuery:

```
console.log($("input[type='radio']:checked").next());
```

Bear in mind that since these are radio buttons, you shouldn't label both as `checked`.